# Create an observable that emits subsets of data from another observable

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable `values$` that emits objects.

```
const value = { a: { foo: bar }};
const values$ = Observable.from([value, value, value]);
```

I'm trying to create another observable from `values$` that emits the value of `a` everytime `values$` fires. I've been scouring the docs looking for an operator that would allow me to do this but I've not found anything.

Right now I am adding extra logic each time the observable is to be subscribed to, but it feels wrong.

```
const innerValueSubject = new Subject();
const innerValue$ = innerValueSubject.asObservable();

values$.do(value => innerValueSubject.next(value))
    .subscribe(...);

innerValue$.map(value => value.a)
    .subscribe(...);
```

Is there a way I can derive `innerValue$` from `values$` and then just map to get the result I need each time `values$` emits?

Comment: So you want `values$.map(value => value.a)`?

Comment: Well ultimately yes, but this question is focused more on how I can derive the observable `innerValue$` from the original observable without creating a separate subject and manually calling `next`.

Comment: Updated the last code snippet to represent that.

Comment: Well, `innerValue$ = values$.map(value => value.a);`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thinking about it. It's so obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deriving observables from existing observables you just need to reference the existing observable that is returned by each operator.

In my case

```
const innerValue$ = values$.map(value => value.a);
```

thanks to @JBNizet for the comment on the question.